# What is meant by "phase space structure"?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-space, non-equilibrium

I've heard that non-equilibrium systems have the property that their phase space has a structure, as opposed to 'structure-less' phases spaces of equilibrium systems. What does this precisely mean? 
I'm not alluding to the [symplectic structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#Mathematical_formalism) of Hamiltonian systems, as many non-equilibrium systems are dissipative and therefore not Hamiltonian.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Heard where?

Comment: Consider this from the perspective of a micro-canonical system: In equilibrium all states on the submanifold the energy restricts to are equally likely, so the distribution in phase space is "featureless", in a non-equilibrium system there will be "features" in the sense, that not all states are equally likely. Similar statements will be possible about other ensembles (which can be though of as a part of a micro-canonical ensemble).

Comment: Some dissipative systems approach attractor sets with fractal structure.  Turbulence is one such phenomenon.  The theory of chaos offers more examples.